# Fixing "The field Price must be a number." in Microsoft .NET Core / ASP.NET Tutorial

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Suppose you have followed the steps from Microsoft

[Tutorial: Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

i.e. created the project "RazorPagesMovie"

using Visual Studio Core and you are using a different localization then the default one - for example de-DE for german language. In that case you will face an issue when modifying the "Price" of a Movie using

https://localhost:5001/Movies/Edit?id=1

giving an error like

"The field Price must be a number."

To fix this issue

(1) Edit inside Project "RazorPagesMovie" the file

```
RazorPagesMovie\Pages\Shared\_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml
```

and add following lines:

```
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-globalize/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

(2) Download NodeJS from

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

and install NodeJS as administrative user for example into

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

(3) Open Commandline cmd.exe as administrative user and goto NodeJS install folder - see (2)

```
cd C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

and perform

```
npm install globalize cldrjs jquery-validation-globalize cldr-data iana-tz-data
```

(4) copy required JavaScript-files to `wwwroot\lib` folder of Project

For example if

```
c:\DOTNET\RazorPagesMovie\
```

is the project folder, perform

```
cd c:\DOTNET\RazorPagesMovie\wwwroot\lib
Xcopy /E /I "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\globalize" %CD%\globalize
Xcopy /E /I "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cldrjs" %CD%\cldrjs
Xcopy /E /I "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\jquery-validation-globalize" %CD%\jquery-validation-globalize
```

(5) Build and run project
Entering values using local decimal and group separators should now work.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing this solution on this forum, It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues.

Besides, it seems that this is a known issue: *You may not be able to enter decimal commas in decimal fields. To support jQuery validation for non-English locales that use a comma (",") for a decimal point, and non US-English date formats, you must take steps to globalize your app. See [this GitHub issue 4076](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420) for instructions on adding decimal comma.* More detail information, check article: [add validation to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I know the both discussions - unfortunatly both lack of a simple, short and easy way to workaround for people facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is that these libraries do not see "," as a number and return an error.**

You can customize this library.
Make sure you have the jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js files in your project. These libraries are responsible for performing validation operations in the browser and are commonly used in ASP.NET MVC applications.

Download the latest versions of the jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js files, if needed, or use the ones already included in your project. You can obtain these files from the official jQuery Validation website.

To customize the validation behavior, add the following code to your JavaScript file:

Customize validation options

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  // Add your customization options here
});
```

Customize validation rules

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
  // Perform your custom validation logic here
  // Return true/false based on the validation result
};

$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
  // Perform your custom validation logic here
  // Return true/false based on the validation result
};
```

In the code above, you can use the $.validator.setDefaults method to customize the validation options. Additionally, you can modify specific validation rules such as number and range using the $.validator.methods object.